# How to see the query plan for PostgreSQL for FKs

Tags: postgresql

On postgres, is there a way to view the query plan for referential integrity affected queries.

For example, an insert is performed to a table that has a foreign key defined to another table. There is an internal lookup that is performed to ensure the referenced table has a PK with that value.

Another example, a delete on a referenced table in a FK sets the referencing table's column to null when the referenced table has the row deleted.

I recently had a delete being performed on a PK table and the FK referencing table was having a seq scan (table scan) of 1.5 million rows for every delete on the PK table.  The FK declared the column to be set to null on delete.  The problem was resolved by looking the the DDL for the tables and figuring out what was occurring.

Any way to easily review the complete query plan including internal lookup references?  Without the ability to look at the RI query plans, it is not easy to determine what is causing the poor performance.

Comment: `explain (analyze, timing)` will show the _time_ it took for the FK checks, but not the actual SQL that was run to do that.

Comment: *Referencing table was having a seq scan ...*. Sounds like a good reason to index the FK.

Comment: Looking for a way to easily determine that there is a internal FK lookup, update or delete(cascade) for a corresponding SQL statement.